# what constraints are carried forward in the '' create table as" statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Create table a as select * from b;
```

What are all the `constraints` those are carried forward  from `table  b` to table `table a` in the above select statement ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (I'd be surprised if the answer is the same for all of them.)

Comment: it gives syntax error in _sql server_ !!

Comment: Hi Mat,I am using oracle .probably you can a general answer not specific to any database.that would be great.

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi: `create table .. as select ...` is (standard) ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, only the "not null" constraints are carried over with this statement. You must create all the others constraints afterwards.